# ScriptIntrincisConvolve3x3: Output-Allocation float4 instead of U8_4?

Tags: android, convolution, renderscript

I have no problem applying the ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 (or 5x5) function for in- and output allocations being both  U8_4. But if I want to apply the convolution to a gradient filter such as Sobel I need an output of type float (not U8_4), because I need to consider also the NEGATIVE output values. This  question was raised here already 18 month ago but has not been answered yet. Any help is highly appreciated.

[Android RenderScript copy allocation in rs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705061/android-renderscript-copy-allocation-in-rs-file)

Comment: Just to clarify: do you need to preserve Gx and Gy output from Sobel filter separately, or do you plan to combine them to get non-negative gradient magnitude? If latter is the case, you only need negative values temporarily. It will be much faster to have a custom script compute both Gx and Gy convolutions in a single pass and store combined result in U8_4.

Comment: Miloslaw, good point. Indeed it would be great to get the magnitude array plus the direction array in one Renderscript pass. I don't want to be pathetic, but, unfortunately, after three weeks doing intense research on Renderscript I resignated, since there is no documentation and I want to understand what I do. Also, I even struggle setting up a ridiculous .rs folder, with an rs. script that is recognised by Java as Script_C object.... Therefore I try to make optimal use of the Intrinsic Functions (e.g. Gauss Blur) and solving this Sobel problem would bring me the speed I need.

Comment: This can be done, but will be far from optimal: you will have to convert bitmap data to float first, since ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 requires input and output Allocations to be of the same type. Then you will have two kernel passes, and finally a conversion to gradient magnitude in Java. I'd (again) suggest that you try to "Import sample..." to an empty project, so that you can analyse build scripts etc. And by the way, how did you set up the "rs" folder? By hand or using "New/Folder/Renderscript folder"? Because I've just did the latter on a clean project and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, below you have all the important parts. It's been copied from a working code, hopefully I did not miss anything. Computing gradient magnitude in Java using `out` and `out2` allocations is left as an exercise for the reader. ;) Again, it would be much faster (and cleaner) to do it all in one Renderscript pass.

```
public class MainActivity {
  private RenderScript mRS;
  private Allocation mInAllocation;
  Type.Builder TypeIn;

  private void createScript(Bitmap mBitmapIn) {
    mRS = RenderScript.create(this);

    TypeIn = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.F32_4(mRS));

    mInAllocation = createFromBitmap_F32_4(mRS, mBitmapIn);

    mScriptConvolve = ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3.create(mRS,
            Element.F32_4(mRS));

  }

  private Allocation createFromBitmap_F32_4(RenderScript rs, Bitmap b)
  {
    int w = b.getWidth();
    int h = b.getHeight();
    int idx = 0;

    Allocation atn = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, TypeIn.setX(w).setY(h).create());
    float []temp = new float[w * h * 4];

    for(int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            int pix = b.getPixel(x, y);

            temp[idx++] = 255.f;
            temp[idx++] = (float)((pix >>> 16) & 0xff);
            temp[idx++] = (float)((pix >>> 8) & 0xff);
            temp[idx++] = (float)(pix & 0xff);
        }

    atn.copyFrom(temp);

    return atn;
  }

  private void allocationToBitmap(Allocation atn, Bitmap bmp)
  {
    int w = bmp.getWidth();
    int h = bmp.getHeight();
    int idx = 0;

    float []temp = new float[w * h * 4];
    atn.copyTo(temp);

    for(int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            int a = 255; idx++;
            int r = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, (int)temp[idx++]));
            int g = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, (int)temp[idx++]));
            int b = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, (int)temp[idx++]));

            bmp.setPixel(x, y, (a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b));
        }
  }

  private void performFilter(Allocation inAllocation,
                           Bitmap bitmapOut) {

            Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, TypeIn.create());
            Allocation out2 = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, TypeIn.create());

            // Emboss filter kernel

            float coefficients[] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
            float coefficients2[] = {-1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1};

            mScriptConvolve.setCoefficients(coefficients);
            mScriptConvolve.setInput(inAllocation);
            mScriptConvolve.forEach(out);  // Gx

            mScriptConvolve.setCoefficients(coefficients2);
            mScriptConvolve.setInput(inAllocation);
            mScriptConvolve.forEach(out2); // Gy

            allocationToBitmap(out2, bitmapOut);
  }
```

Comment: I rearranged your code, but I get a runtime error at the assignment of ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3.create(rs, Element.F32_4(rs)); it say android.support.v8.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Unsuported element type. Anyway I learned a lot on this example, which is really not clean nor elegant, as you said above; and I clearly see that I need to implement it in Renderscript myself, I will try my best. As with regards to the magnitude calc I use a proxy for hypot which is much quicker. Thanks anyway.

Comment: private float proxyHypot(float a, float b){
        float a1 = (float) Math.abs(a);
        float b1 = (float) Math.abs(b);
        if (a1<=b1) {
            return 0.426f*a1+0.936f*b1;
        }
        else {
            return 0.426f*b1+0.936f*a1;
        }
    }

Comment: What phone/OS do you run this on?

Comment: It didn't work on my Samsung Galaxy Tab2, but now it works with the Galaxy S5 - but far from being efficient. Will learn RenderScript now, it is not all that difficult (seems that I was impatient the last days...).